# Recursive Loop when trying to fetch models

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent

**MYSQL**

```
#advertisements
`id` -> primary key
`title` -> varchar(100)

#advertisementsTags
```

`id` -> primary key
    `tag` -> varchar(40)

```
#advertisements_has_tags
`tag_id`  
`ad_id`  
##Foreign keys
fk_tag_id for column `tag_id` points to `AdvertisementsTags`.`id` 
fk_ad_id for column `ad_id` points to `Advertisements`.`id`
```

**AdvertisementsModel**

```
   public function tags(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Advertisements\AdvertisementTagsModel','advertisement_has_tags','fk_ad_id','id');
    }
```

**AdvertisementTagsModel**

```
  public function advertisements(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Advertisements\AdvertisementsModel','advertisement_has_tags','fk_tag_id','id');
    }
```

**AdvertisementsController**

```
  public function index(){
        $finder = AdvertisementsModel::find(1);
        $tags=$finder->tags();
        echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($tags);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

When i enter the `/advertisements` route which calls the `index()` of `AdvertisementsController` it falls into a recursive loop, i just cant managed to declare properly this relationship between Advertisements and Tags.

After calling `$tags()->get()` got the following sql error, don't know how it build that query. Why it builds `as`pivot_fk_ad_id``

```
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
'advertisement_has_tags.fk_ad_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select 
`advertisement_tags`.*, `advertisement_has_tags`.`fk_ad_id` as `pivot_fk_ad_id`,
 `advertisement_has_tags`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `advertisement_tags` inner 
join `advertisement_has_tags` on `advertisement_tags`.`id` = 
`advertisement_has_tags`.`id` where `advertisement_has_tags`.`fk_ad_id` = 1)
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you sure the loop is because of the relationship? Maybe it's something with your routes or even htaccess?

Comment: when i just use `var_dump('hello world');` it dumps `hello world` maybe its `var_dump` which tries to traverse the result?

Comment: Your mySQL notation confuses me a bit. What are the fieldnames? Perhaps you need to use `tag_id` instead of `fk_tag_id` and `ad_id`  instead of `fk_ad_id`?

Comment: `fk_ad_id` and `fk_tag_id` are the foreign keys of the `Advertisements_has_tags` will edit to make it more clear

Comment: First of all try to use `$finder->tags()->get()`, since you're using the method access

Comment: i got an sql error , when i try to call `->get()` still dont understand how it builds that query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of struggling it worked when i made the following changes.

**AdvertisementsModel** switched parameters to `'ad_id','tag_id');`

**AdvertisementTagsModel** switched parameters to `'tag_id','ad_id');`

**AdvertisementsController**

```
  public function index(){
        $finder = AdvertisementsModel::find(1);
        $tags=$finder->tags()->get();
        echo '<pre>';
            foreach($tags as $t){
             echo $t->tag."\n";
            }
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

to bad that laravel didn't provide enough documentation..